# Proguard not including a particular file

Tags: android, proguard

I have the following code:

```
public class MyJsonObjectRequest extends JsonObjectRequest implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7578115859225594995L;
    private Map<String, String> params = null;

    public MyJsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest, Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, Map<String, String> params) {
        super(method, url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener);
        this.params = params;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        ...
    }
}
```

Whenever I use proguard, I get error such as the below:

```
Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/myapp/MyJsonObjectRequest; (1830)
```

`JsonObjectRequest` is from the `volley` library. Why is it not being included?

I have the following in my proguard file:

```
-keep class com.android.volley.** { *; }
-keep class java.io.** { *; }
```

Is there something else i'm missing? The class is just not being included. It's being called from another class which extends `Application` inside a static method.